# SQLite: trouble building FTS5 loadable extension

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm on Mac trying to build FTS5 as loadable extension.

I've downloaded the SQLite sources, successfully executed `./configure` and `make fts5`, obtained `fts5.{c,h}` files.

Now when trying to build the dynamic library for the extension I get:

```
gcc -g -fPIC -dynamiclib -o fts5.dylib fts5.c
In file included from fts5Int.h:18:0:
fts5_storage.c: In function 'sqlite3Fts5StorageOpen':
fts5_storage.c:305:9: error: 'sqlite3_api_routines' has no member named '__builtin___snprintf_chk'
In file included from /usr/include/secure/_string.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:192,
                 from fts5Int.h:21:
fts5_storage.c:305:26: warning: passing argument 1 of '__builtin_object_size' makes pointer from integer without a cast
fts5_storage.c:305:26: note: expected 'const void *' but argument is of type 'int'
In file included from fts5Int.h:18:0:
fts5_storage.c:308:11: error: 'sqlite3_api_routines' has no member named '__builtin___snprintf_chk'
In file included from /usr/include/secure/_string.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:192,
                 from fts5Int.h:21:
fts5_storage.c:308:28: warning: passing argument 1 of '__builtin_object_size' makes pointer from integer without a cast
fts5_storage.c:308:28: note: expected 'const void *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried gcc 4.9 and 5.5 from MacPorts on macOS

---

Interesting enough, on Linux (and with gcc5) I'm getting this error:

```
❯ gcc -g -fPIC -shared -o fts5.so fts5.c
fts5.h:24:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

And sure enough there's no sqlite3.h in the root of the sources directory, though I expect it should be created during the make step?
I can of course install libsqlite3-dev but I already have all the sqlite sources, why should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dan Kennedy from the SQLite dev team the issue is now resolved.

The 1st issue appeared to be the actual problem with SQLite source code when compiled on macOS, and it's now fixed here: http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/cd0471ca9f75e7c8

The 2nd problem was about the header file not generated because it requires a separate make step. So the full build instructions actually look like this:

```
./configure
make fts5.c sqlite3.h sqlite3ext.h
gcc -O2 -fPIC -shared fts5.c -o fts5.dylib
```